# Erro PHP ligar a base de dados em servidor

Tags: php, sql

Estou com uma duvida **quando mudo as credenciais** da base de dados  em localhost para as credenciais da base de dados em **sql server** da-me este **erro no php**

```
    Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Este anfitrião não é conhecido. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Contactos_BD\conexao.php on line 6

    Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Este anfitrião não é conhecido. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Contactos_BD\conexao.php on line 6
```

Codigo:

```
$host="*host*";
$usuario="*user**";
$senha="*pass**";
$bd="*bd**";
$mysqli= new mysqli($host,$usuario,$senha,$bd);
$mysqli=mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$senha,$bd);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Parece-me que estão erradas. Consegue conectar com elas diretamente no banco sem ser pelo PHP?

Comment: Sim,pelo o localhost o problema é que quando entro pelas credenciais do servidor não dá,o sql management studio entra e posso executar query's sem problema (com as mesmas credencias do server)

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar como está fazendo a conexão? Lembre-se de alterar o usuário e senha antes de postar aqui por segurança.

Comment: Já está atualizado!

Comment: É problema com o Host.

Comment: Então como posso resolver?

Comment: Duas possibilidades: você está tentando acessar um host incorreto, logo não podemos ajudar, pq não sabemos qual é. Outra é: teu host do banco tem firewall e só permite um certo range de IPs acessar, e teu script php está em outro servidor com IP que não é do range permitido.

Answer (score 2):

Usa a função [`sqlsrv_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) podes ir ao site do Php para saber mais sobre essa função